# How to search for a pattern using grep and exclude another pattern

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I have been looking at several other answers and couldn't find what I want.

I have a big file with some urls in it and I am looking for urls which have the pattern tt in them.
Of course every line has http in it. so if I do

```
grep tt myfile | wc -l
```

I get all the lines of the file.
How can I find patterns which match tt, without matching http?

I tried with --exclude and it doesn't work, I think exclude only works on the path, right?

I could use sed and replace http by something else and then grep normally, but how elegant is that? there must be another way...

Comment: I guess i'll replace all the http by #### and just use grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the next test file

```
some text http://example.com/redirect?http://some/test.html             #not wanted
some text http://example.com/notete.html                                #not wanted
some text http://example.com/redirect?http://some/anyttany.html         #wanted
some text http://example.com/http.html                                  #wanted
some text http://example.com/tt.html                                    #wanted
some text http://example.com/somett.html                                #wanted
some text http://example.com/somettsome.html                            #wanted
some text /example.com/somettsome.html                                  #wanted (path only)
```

the next:

```
grep -P 'http://\S*tt(?!p:)' file
```

prints

```
some text http://example.com/redirect?http://some/anyttany.html         #wanted
some text http://example.com/http.html                                  #wanted
some text http://example.com/tt.html                                    #wanted
some text http://example.com/somett.html                                #wanted
some text http://example.com/somettsome.html                            #wanted
```

mean

```
  http://                  'http://'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \S*                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (0 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  tt                       'tt'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    p:                       'p:'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and the

```
grep -cP 'http://\S*tt(?!p:)' file
```

will count the matched lines

if the `http://` at the start is optional,

```
 grep -P '(<=http://)?\S*tt(?!p:)' file
```

will do the same job and for the same input prints

```
some text http://example.com/redirect?http://some/anyttany.html         #wanted
some text http://example.com/http.html                                  #wanted
some text http://example.com/tt.html                                    #wanted
some text http://example.com/somett.html                                #wanted
some text http://example.com/somettsome.html                            #wanted
some text /example.com/somettsome.html                                  #wanted (path only)
```

for capturing the URL's (and paths)

```
grep -oP '.*?\K(http:/)?/\S*tt(?!p:)\S*' file
```

prints

```
http://example.com/redirect?http://some/anyttany.html
http://example.com/http.html
http://example.com/tt.html
http://example.com/somett.html
http://example.com/somettsome.html
/example.com/somettsome.html
```

capturing only `http://`

```
grep -oP '.*?\Khttp://\S*tt(?!p:)\S*' file

http://example.com/redirect?http://some/anyttany.html
http://example.com/http.html
http://example.com/tt.html
http://example.com/somett.html
http://example.com/somettsome.html
```

Comment: simple and effective!

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if the line doesn't begin with `http`?

Comment: @AmalMurali The OP says: _Of course every line has http in it._

Comment: @jm666: Yes, but that's not the same as: "*Of course every line **begins with** http*"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-P` switch to have `grep` interpret the pattern as a Perl regular expression. Then you can use lookaround assertions to match `tt`s that are ***not*** preceded by `h` and ***not*** followed by `p://`.

```
grep -iP '(?<!h)tt(?!ps?://)' myfile | wc -l
```

Comment: exactly and that's my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` like this

```
cat file:
http://example.com
http://google.com
my.tt.com
t.foo.bar
http://foobar.com
http://example.com/somett.html
http://example.com/http.html
http://example.com/notete.html
http://example.com/tt.html
http://example.com/somett.html
http://example.com/somettsome.html
```

```
awk -F"http:" '$NF~/tt/'
my.tt.com
http://example.com/somett.html
http://example.com/http.html
http://example.com/tt.html
http://example.com/somett.html
http://example.com/somettsome.html
```

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep -c 'http://[^ ?]*tt' YourFile
```

- -c four count
- egrep for regex (you can use `grep -E` also) pattern that allow to exclude the http part of the search criteria
- add and exclusion of space/special url char (suggestion from comment of Jotne and following) to avoid taking tt from a eventual second url on the same line.

Comment: This assume line does contain  `http` to start with. If that is the case, then its ok.

Comment: @Jotne the OP says: _Of course every line has http in it._

Comment: @jm666: OP doesn't say the line **begins** with `http`.

Comment: this does not assume line start with hhtp:// but that line contain http://. In fact, it assume that tt is after http:// so it fail if tt if before (is the case possible here ? and should it be take into account in this configuration, not sur becasue it tell taking URL, whatever is around it on the line. So it works if there is at least 1 url starting with http://and having tt inside. I just adapt to remove space betweeh http and tt (taking th tt fron next http:// )

Answer (score 0):

you can use grep -v to exclude the lines with a pattern like this

```
grep tt myfile | grep -v http | wc -l
```

This give, first of all, the lines with "tt", then exclude those with "http" and then count it.